# How to detect iframe tab window with original window link on selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, iframe, webdriver

[image: Ifram]

I have a problem with iframe tab. My web page have an iframe in the separate tab which is open using 3rd party link. I want to catch that like by go every tab but not getting any way to do.

HTML CODE :

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <li class="resp-tab-item resp-tab-active" aria-controls="tab_item-0" role="tab">
        <a class="js-tab-list js-tab-1" data-source="https://www.adsdssas.com/property/individual/BC-2030877?isl=1" data-no="1" data-ga="0" target="iframe_1">
            <img src="/themes/centralization/images/partners-tab-logo/rentalhomes-tab-logo.png" alt="RentalHomes.com" height="20" width="auto">
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-1" role="tab">
        <a class="js-tab-list js-tab-1" data-source="https://www.jdoasdadadqocy.com/click-8111003-11553823?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vrasbo.com%2Fvacation-rentals%3Fq%3DDauphin%2BIsland%252C%2BAL%252C%2BUSA&amp;utm_campaign=RENTALHOMES&amp;sid=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;label=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;ft=1" data-no="1" data-ga="0" target="iframe_1">
            <img src="/themes/centralization/images/partners-tab-logo/feed_logo_vrbo.png" alt="VRBO.Com" height="20" width="auto">
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-2" role="tab">
        <a class="js-tab-list js-tab-1" data-source="https://www.jdadsdoqocy.com/click-8111003-10859031?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homeaway.com%2Fresults%2Fkeywords%3ADauphin%2BIsland%252C%2BAL%252C%2BUSA&amp;utm_campaign=RENTALHOMES&amp;sid=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;label=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;ft=1" data-no="1" data-ga="0" target="iframe_1">
            <img src="/themes/centralization/images/partners-tab-logo/feed_logo_12.png" alt="HomeAway.Com" height="20" width="auto">
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-3" role="tab">
        <a class="js-tab-list js-tab-1" data-source="https://www.dddoaoa.com/click-8111003-11327743?url=https://www.asdasd.com/search.do?q-destination=Dauphin+Island%2C+AL%2C+USA&amp;utm_campaign=RENTALHOMES&amp;sid=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;label=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;ft=1" data-no="1" data-ga="0" target="iframe_1">
            <img src="/themes/centralization/images/partners-tab-logo/feed_logo_14.png" alt="Hotel.Com" height="20" width="auto">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any type of help will be appreciated

```
Thanks @anshul
```

I run your code but its print same url 4 times.I want to take iframe url and

```
@Test
public void DetailsPageSliderTAB_For_BC() throws InterruptedException{
    wd.manage().window().maximize();
    wd.get("http://192.168.2.116/check/");
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Rentalhomes']/div/div/div/table/tbody[4]/tr[6]/td[1]/a")).click();

    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String HotelonBCP=wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='air-bnb-checkbox checkbox']")).getText();
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lightbox-pop']/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='start_now11']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(200000);
    Reporter.log("POP Under Name "+HotelonBCP);


    for (String windows : wd.getWindowHandles()) {

        wd.switchTo().window(windows);

        if (wd.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("http://staging.rentalhomes.com")) {
            List<WebElement> liElementList = wd.findElement(By.id("horizontalTabAffiliate")).findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'resp-tabs-list')]")).findElements(By.tagName("li"));

             for (WebElement webElement : liElementList) {
             // Based on the webElement perform operation
                 wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='horizontalTabAffiliate']/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
                 System.out.println(wd.getCurrentUrl());
            }
        }
        }
    }


 <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-1" role="tab">
                        <a class="js-tab-list js-tab-1" data-source="https://www.jdoqocy.com/click-8111003-11553823?url=p;ft=1" data-no="1" data-ga="0" target="iframe_1">
                            <img src="/themes/centralization/images/partners-tab-logo/feed_logo_vrbo.png" alt="VRBO.Com" height="20" width="auto">
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: can you be little bit clear, Do you want to get all those links which opens in iframe ? or do you want to  cick on the link then > move to new tab as link opened in and then > find the iframe and perform your actions with some element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
List<WebElement> liElementList = driver.findElement(By.id("horizontalTabAffiliate")).findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'resp-tabs-list')]")).findElements(By.tagName("li"));

 for (WebElement webElement : liElementList) {
 // Based on the webElement perform operation
}
```

Explanation :
 1. Firstly, I am location it from the parent div element which **findElement(By.id("horizontalTabAffiliate"))** this will locate the outer div using it's id.

2. Once the parenet div is located, you can start location the inner elements in your case innerElement is an **"ul"**, as per the DOM there is only one ul present.**findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'resp-tabs-list')]"))**  this will locate the ul element with the help of the parent div.
3. Once you the ul located, you can get a list of the innermost **"li"** element. **findElements(By.tagName("li"))** , this will return a list of the li elements. So you will be having all the tabs located on the above panel which are your third party links.

   4. Once these elements are located you can easily perform operation based on that. For your case if you are only interested on clicking the first element of "li", do simply **webs.click();** in your for loop().

**Note** you can do much more with the li elements list once it is located. Also make sure the name of class, id's, tagname which I have used above are correct and matching with your DOM.

Let me know if this works, or you need more details.

Comment: Thank you so much..I edit my post please check.Here I want to take current URL and I want to take frame data URL like data source="https://www.jdoqocy.com....
Please see my post.below I added HTML code where i need that like and iframe tab URL